# Spring cloud Greenwich x Hoxton x Ilford

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

Can anyone explain me the difference between the first two? I can see when i go to docs that it says CURRENT next to Hoxton.

I guess the third is going to be released this year so not many people can tell me what is going to be new and different.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greenwich is not supported anymore. Hoxton is a supported GA release train (that's why its releases are marked as current = the most recent GA release). Service releases are being done for that release train. 2020.0.0 (previously called Ilford) is the release train that is currently under development - the first milestone (M1) has been released and M2 will be coming next.

Comment: Thank you very much. I saw that it is "bound" also to Spring Boot version, so i was a bit confused. Thanks again, and stay safe!

Comment: It's paired with a Spring Boot version in the sense that a certain version of Spring Cloud, for example, `Hoxton.SR3` only supports certain version (or more) of Spring Boot. The easiest way to make sure the dependencies are matched correctly is to generate a project at start.spring.io.